# increment the i

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i=1;i<=($("input:regex(id,[0-9]+)").length);i++)
{
    array.push($("#i").val());
}
```

Hey, I am tying to store the input value in the array. Each of the input has distinct id associated with it, in this case, 1,2,3,4 and so on. How can I change the i in

```
array.push($("#i").val());
```

accordingly with the counter i in the for loop, which would fetch the value from inputs. like if I got two inputs fields, whose ids are 1 and 2. After this codes execution, the array has two elements that are from the inputs. Thank you

Comment: What's with the extra parens?

Comment: Better performance: `for (var i = 1, len = $('input:regex(id,[0-9]+)').length; i < len; i++)`. You are doing a jQuery lookup on every iteration which is a performance nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do, just use a + sign to concat the string of "#" with the number from `i`

```
for(var i=1;i<=($("input:regex(id,[0-9]+)").length);i++)
{
    array.push($("#"+i).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the string concatenation, or `+` operator:

```
array.push($("#" + i).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you change the i in the expression? Do you mean like `array.push($("#"+i).val());`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[id]').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).val());
});
```

Hope I got it right because It is hard to understand your question!

Answer (score 0):

You could map the values instead of looping over each one of them.

```
var array = $("input:regex(id,[0-9]+)").map(function() { 
    return this.value;
}).get();
```